# How to fix jQuery Modal acts different only on safari browser on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, modal-dialog, mobile-safari

I've searched many solutions but still didn't find the right one!

So my issue is that the Modal acts on safari iPhone different then any other place.

After the user clicks on input field in a form. the keyboard hides a part of the form which means hide buttons and some input fields. in order to solve that i added padding-bottom but that doesn't work on the iphone.

so is there a way to force modal on iphone safari to be 100% width and 100% height, and scrollable, without the keyboard hiding part of the modal on the bottom side?

in addition to that you know iphone by default zoom the page automatically when you focus on an input field. so this itself is another issue.

Best solution that i've found so far that worked fine everywhere.
**https://get.foundation/sites/docs/reveal.html#full-screen**

but in my solution i have to stick to jquery 1.9.1 & jquery-ui 1.9.2

[IMG1: fields shows normal before opening keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0G6A.png)
[IMG2: keyboard hides some fields and modal goes bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcElZ.png)

Comment: still seeking solution for this issue.
Dialog Modals behave different and wrong on Safari browser on Mobile.
the only solution so far is to to add padding buttom in order to see fields that are hidden by the ios mobile keyboard